# Staff column for my stored procedure does not always generate information

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So my stored procedure has a staff column that should be generating a staff name from my `Employee` table. The staff name only shows up on for some of the rows. Can anyone take a look and see where my error is here:

```
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [user] (NOLOCK) 
               WHERE [user].ID = @UserID 
                 AND [user].BrandID IS NULL AND [user].SpaID IS NULL)
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @OrderStatusID_Completed int, @OrderStatusID_Shipped int

    SET @OrderStatusID_Shipped = 4
    SET @OrderStatusID_Completed = 2

    SELECT 
        CAST('' AS varchar(50)) AS ErrMsg
        , o.OrderNumber
        , Customer.GUID AS CustomerGUID
        , OrderItem_View.DateCreated AS ItemDate
        , COALESCE(MasterProductVariant.SKU, ProductVariant.SKU, Treatment.SKU) AS SKU
        , DynamicPrice.FinalPrice AS Price
        --, COALESCE(MasterProductVariant.OriginalPrice, ProductVariant.OriginalPrice, Treatment.Price) AS Price
        , ISNULL(Employee.FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(Employee.LastName,'') AS Staff
        , COALESCE(Product.Name, Treatment.Name) AS Item
        , NULL AS Note
    FROM
        [Order] o (Nolock)
    LEFT JOIN 
        Customer (Nolock) ON o.CustomerID = Customer.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        OrderItem_View (nolock) ON OrderItem_View.OrderID = o.ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        DynamicPrice (nolock) ON OrderItem_View.DynamicPriceID = DynamicPrice.ID
    LEFT JOIN 
        AppointmentTreatment WITH (NOLOCK) ON AppointmentTreatment.ID = OrderItem_View.AppointmentTreatmentID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Employee (NOLOCK) ON Employee.ID = COALESCE(OrderItem_View.EmployeeID, OrderItem_View.Employee2ID, AppointmentTreatment.EmployeeID)
    LEFT JOIN 
        Treatment_View Treatment (nolock) ON Treatment.BillableItemID = OrderItem_View.BillableItemID
    LEFT JOIN 
        ProductVariant (NOLOCK) 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Product (NOLOCK) ON Product.ID = ProductVariant.ProductID
            ON ProductVariant.BillableItemID = OrderItem_View.BillableItemID
    LEFT JOIN 
        ProductVariant MasterProductVariant (NOLOCK) ON ProductVariant.MasterRecordID = MasterProductVariant.ID
    WHERE 
        o.SpaID = @SpaID
        AND o.IsDeleted = 0
        AND o.DateCompleted >= CONVERT(DATETIME,0)
        AND o.DateCompleted < GetDate() 
        AND o.StatusID IN (@OrderStatusID_Completed,@OrderStatusID_Shipped)
END
ELSE
    SELECT CAST('Insufficient rights.' AS VARCHAR(50)) AS ErrMsg
END
```

Comment: maybe not related but do you understand what nolock mean?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary

Answer (score 2):

It has to be in the coalesce function.  Somewhere between these three - you aren't getting a value

`OrderItem_View.EmployeeID`
`OrderItem_View.Employee2ID`
`AppointmentTreatment.EmployeeID`

So run OrderItem_View by itself and see if there are instances where EmployeeID or Employee2ID is ever null.  If so, then try to determine what employees are missing.  IF there are employees missing, are they also missing in the AppointmentTreatment table?  If so then therein lies the problem.